# Http Response Code for Expected Server Error

Tags: http, exception, http-response-codes

What is the recommended HTTP response code for an expected server error? I know that 500 is for a server error, but it is typically for an unexpected error.

What if you wanted to throw an exception and allow the client to deal with it? Doesn't a 500 response code seem incorrect for that? What number should be used?

Comment: What is an "expected server error"?

Comment: how possible could a client handle a server error? Clients can handle client errors (4xx)

Comment: Say that there's a website that you can put in your email and sign up for a newsletter. The website posts a call to our server. We do a spam check. If it is spam, we throw an exception. It's something we fully anticipate will happen to some degree. So it's an exception on the server, but not something that we have to deal with since it's just a rest service. The web site can deal with it however it wants (one way is to tell the user that the email is spam ... or to not saying anything at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP response codes should only reflect the status of the request itself. Something like a spam filter is endemic to the workings of your application, and has no bearing on the status of the HTTP request and response. Similar question here: [How to show the internal server errors to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134696/how-to-show-the-internal-server-errors-to-the-user/)

Answer (score 1):

> The website posts a call to our server. We do a spam check. If it is spam, we throw an exception.

That is not an expected server error, that's a client performing an invalid request. Take a look at the 4xx range.